# Having trouble running a command line application

Tags: haskell, command-line, command-prompt

I'm trying to run [this Haskell program called Rattletrap](https://github.com/tfausak/rattletrap), but I can't seem to get it to work. I downloaded the code from GitHub into "C:\Programming\RocketLeague", so the path to rattletrap is "C:\Programming\RocketLeague\rattletrap-main". I added this as a Path user variable already and exited/restarted the command prompt. When I type

```
rattletrap --help
```

in the windows command prompt while inside \rattletrap-main, I get the error:

```
'rattletrap' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I've looked at answers to similar questions, and the answers I've found indicate that I need to add the program's *bin* file to PATH, but as far as I can see there is no bin file. I installed Haskell in C:\ and I have C:\ghcup\bin in my user PATH. I feel like there is some really minor thing I'm missing so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the exe name, rattletrap or rattletrap-main?

Comment: There is C:\Programming\RocketLeague\rattletrap-main\src\exe\Main.hs, and I already added that to PATH as well. Main.hs is the only file in \rattletrap-main\src\exe\.

Comment: Are you calling cabal/stack to compile the program?

Comment: Main.hs is a source file, not an executable file. You need compile the project into an executable. You can probably get away with something like `stack run -- --help`

Comment: @pedrofurla compiling the project into an executable was the step I was missing. I did that and successfully ran the program on one of my replay files. Thank you!

Comment: Incidentally, adding a lot of folders to your path is not a good idea. When you install a program (e..g by `stack install`) that should copy the executable into somewhere already in your PATH.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not about programming.